# HMAC URLs instead of login?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, hmac

In implementing my site (a Rails site if it makes any difference), one of my design priorities is to relieve the user of the need to create yet another username and password while still providing useful per-user functionality.

The way I am planning to do this is:

1. User enters information on the site. Information is associated with the user via server-side session.
2. User completes entering information, server sends an access URL via e-mail to the user roughly in the form of: `http://siteurl/<user identifier>/<signature: HMAC(secret + salt + user identifier)>`
3. User clicks URL, site looks up user ID and salt and computes the HMAC with the server-stored secret and authenticates if the computed HMAC and signature match.

My question is: is this a reasonably secure way to accomplish what I'm looking to do? Are there common attacks that would render it useless? Is there a compelling reason to abandon my desire to avoid a username/password? Is there a must-read book or article on the subject?

Note that I'm not dealing with credit card numbers or anything exceedingly private, but I would still like to keep the information reasonably secure.

Comment: Following on @vitaly's answer, you might consider discarding the signature immediately after the initial login hit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One word (well, actually two) - `Referer` header.
The next site your user goes to after visiting yours will see his credentials in this header. Moreover, the user will not be able to change his credentials after they have been compromised that way.

The idea of username/password authentication is that it involves two separate pieces of information - a known user id and an unknown password that can be freely changed on per-user basis. In your system (apart from the Referer thing), there is one single password for all - the "secret." I also suspect it will be reasonably easy to bruteforce the signature (since I know my user id) and recover the secret, rendering the whole system useless.

Comment: The secret can still be per-user, and "login" page can immediately set the session cookie and redirect.

Comment: Is there a way to alleviate the `Referer` concern? If I authenticate the session and immediately redirect to a URL that doesn't contain the credentials, does the concern still apply?

Wouldn't the per-user salt alleviate the brute force concern?

Answer (score 1):

I've pondered similar passwordless login for iPhone apps — the biggest problem for a webapp is that logging in becomes unnecessarily tedious.

That said, here's a simple modification:

1. User enters e-mail address.
2. Server generates a random authentication (e.g. 128 bits of /dev/urandom, base64-encoded) token and saves `H(authtoken)` to the DB along with a timestamp, and then sends an email with `https://example.com/login/userid?auth=authtoken`
3. User clicks URL, server checks that the token is in the DB and not expired, *removes the token from the DB* and sets a session cookie.

Your server needs to store a little more state, but it needed to store state anyway. It works roughly the same as any good password reset flow, which *presumably* makes it *theoretically* no less secure. In practice, however, it does not leave as obvious an audit trail as account-hijack-via-password-reset because the "password reset" flow is now the normal login flow.

You could also do something similar with a MAC and timestamp `(uid,timestamp,MAC_k(uid,timestamp))` — the basic problem there is that anyone with access to the MAC key (e.g. a database backup) can generate arbitrary authentication tokens, and databases are leaked all the time.

When hashing/MACing, beware of "cryptographic splicing" attacks.

Additionally, a common mistake is to reveal whether a given email address has an account (often the login says "invalid email/password" but the password reset flow gives it away — the better way is to always send an email, and say "there's no account associated with this email" *in the email*, ideally in the same number of bytes as the success response!).

Comment: You seem to be reinventing 2-legged OAuth :) http://www.independentid.com/2011/02/does-oauth-have-legs.html